# Listening to transactions in the mempool but I actually want to list to mined ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, transactions, ethereum

Here's my issue.
Currently looking into this line of code to track transactions from a certain wallet in the memory pool.

```
provider.on("pending", async (txHash) => {      
provider.getTransaction(txHash).then(async (tx) => { 
    try {    
 if (tx && Object.keys(addresses).filter(key => {      
   return
 addresses[key].hasIncoming && !addresses[key].blocked;          
 }).map(x => x.toLowerCase()).includes(tx.from.toLowerCase())) {       
 console.log("New transaction from " + tx.from);``
```

I actually want to listen to transactions already mined but can't seem to find anything in:
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--events Since there's no event to it.

Any idea on how should I proceed ?

Did try every single one of those events but nothing returned me the mined transaction hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the `block` event, and then get a list of transactions in the new block.

```
const {ethers} = require("ethers");
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/<api_key>");
provider.on("block", async (blockNumber) => {
    const block = await provider.getBlockWithTransactions();
    for (let tx of block.transactions) {
        // if (tx)
    }
});
```

Docs: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getBlockWithTransactions

Comment: mind get that a little bit more implemented in my code ?
Can't seem to get exactly what's needed
But I think thats the path !